# Reading from SD card

Tags: java, android, file-io, android-sdcard

I am trying to read a simple text file from my SD card using Java, and I can't seem to be able to open it. I am using Eclipse for Mobile Developers on Ubuntu 12.04. Here's the code in the `onCreate()` method of the main activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String status = "Hello, is it me you're looking for?";
    String storageState = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

    File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File f = new File(dir, "textTest.txt");

    if (f.exists()) {
        status = "File is found!";
    } else {
        status = "File is not found!";
    }

    this.text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    text1.setText(status.subSequence(0, status.length()));
}
```

Also, here are some of the constructors I tried for `File f`, none of them worked:

```
File f = new File(dir, "textTest.txt");
File f = new File("/sdcard/textTest.txt");
File f = new File(dir, "mnt/sdcard/textTest.txt");
```

Finally, I checked the external storage state using the `storageState` string above, and the value returned by `Environment.getExternalStorageState()` is [`mounted`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#MEDIA_MOUNTED). The only lead I have is I think there might be something to do with whether the SD card is readable or not, but that's just a guess. Any ideas?

**Added:**
In case you haven't guessed, the `TextView` object reads "*File not found!*" when I launch the activity.

**Added 2:**
Ok, I just tried something that worked. When I connect the phone via USB, two folders related to the phone open: one which has all of the folders from the internal storage (data, DCIM... etc) and the folder which I assume is connected to the SD card, since I added the files through my laptop card reader and then input it into the phone. However, when I copy the file "testText.txt" into the first folder (which I assumed is related to the internal storage), the constructor `File f = new File("/sdcard/textTest.txt");` works. Howcome?

Comment: do u have `write_external_storage` permission in your manifest?

Comment: No, but I am not trying to write onto a file anyway. I am trying to read. And according to this link: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29, read_external_storage is for future releases

Comment: If you look at the logcat, probably it will warn you if you need to declare any permissions needed.

Comment: Do you get any exceptions while reading the file? What's the result of calling `f.exists()` or `f.isFile()`?

Comment: Guys, it just worked, but I don't understand why, so I'll add it to the question above

Comment: Ok, please see "Added 2:" above

Answer (score 0):

Based on comments..

Add this to your **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

Also if you do somethings with WRITE operation add this permission

```
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

Comment: The `android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` is not enforced at this moment in time, and it was recently added in **API** **16**. Any app that declares the `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`permission is implicitly granted the READ permission.